# php check in javascript on page load

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, codeigniter

I am trying to do something from a while, but with no success.
I hope someone could help me.

Here is **what I want to do**:

In a login page I have two sections:

- 1) login section;
- 2) signup section;

When the page is loaded it only shows the login section (1), because the signup section is with "display:none;".
There is a signup button in the login section and when you hit it, it gives the display:none; to section 1) and makes section 2) display:block;
This way I see only the signup section. 
So far not problems.

**The problem** is when you fill the signup form and you have errors ( lets say you've entered not enough letters for password. )
It reloads the page on form submit and displays the errors.
The **main problem** is that when the page is reloaded, it resets the display:none; order and makes the signup section invisible again.

I've tried:

```
<?php if($this->session->flashdata('error_registration')
<section class="login" style="padding: 20px 28px;display:none;">
<?php else:?>
<section class="login" style="padding: 20px 28px;">
<?php endif;?>
```

Comment: Why don't you handle invalid form inputs in JavaScript itself?

Comment: Why not make another page for `signup`? Also, validate both in JS and on server.

Comment: Your code is formatted incorrectly with some typos.

Comment: Does `$this->session->flashdata('error_registration')` return a boolean?

Comment: why don't you set a flag when posting the data to the server.. like if its from signup page set a flag for that..I guess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could handle it like so...this is only if you have something returning a true/false when checking for errors.

First, put a hidden input in your signup form like

```
<input type="hidden" name="signup" value=1 />
```

Then Check for it to determine the form submitted was the signup form

```
<?php
    // Defaults
    $display_login = ''; // Show Login
    $display_signup = 'display:none;' // Hide Signup

    // If signup form was submitted, check for errors & adjust display of each section
    if(isset($_POST["signup"]){
        $error = $this->session->flashdata('error_registration'); // Must return boolean
        $display_login = $error ? 'display:none;' : ''; // If Error, Hide Login
        $display_signup = $error ? '' : 'display:none;'; // If Error, Show Signup
    }
?>

<section class="login" style="<?= $display_login ?>">
<section class="signup" style="<?= $display_signup ?>">
```

Comment: you have the angular bracket facing the wrong direction ... in the last statement

Answer (score -1):

There are several ways you can do this, here are a few of them:

### Ajax Method (recommended)

(IMHO this is the best approach. This method has the least impact on UX and avoids the issue of showing the divs altogether since you dont reload the page at all.)

```
  $('#login-button').click(function () {
      var $this = $(this);
      var username = $('#userName').val();
      var password = $('#password').val();
      var data = {
          command: "login",
          username: username,
          password: password
      }
      $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: 'login-manager.php',
          data: data,
          success: function (response) {
              if (response.success == true) {
                  window.location = 'homepage.php';
              } 
              else {
                  var error = response.error;
                  // show some error message here
              }
          },
          error: function (xhr, status, error) {
              var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
              console.log(err.Message);
          }
      });
  });
```

Then on `login-manager.php`

```
$data= isset($_POST['data']) ? $_POST['data'] : null;
$command = isset($data['command']) ? $data['command'] : (isset($_POST['command']) ? $_POST['command'] : (isset($_GET['command']) ? $_GET['command'] : null));

if($command == 'login'){
    $username= isset($data['username']) ? $data['username'] : null;
    $password=isset($data['password'])? $data['password'] : null;
    $loginAttempt=login($username,$password);
    // login() should be you own login function and it should return true if the user was logged in or an error message otherwise
    if($loginAttempt===true)
    { 
        echo json_encode(array('success'=>true));
        exit;
    }
    else
    {
        echo json_encode(array('success'=>false,'error'=>$loginAttempt));
        exit;
    }
}

else if($command == 'register'){
    // handle registration logic similarly here
}
```

---

### Get Variables

Submit your form as you currently do

Have some registration function like:

```
session_start();

//....

function register($username, $password,$email){

   // do some registration logic here
  if($someError){
     header('Location: login.php?regErr='.$someError); // redirect the user to the login page with error as get var
  }

}
```

Then on login page do something like this

```
 session_start();

 //....

if(isset($_GET["regErr"])){
                echo '<script> $(function(){ $("#resistrationDiv").show();$("#resistrationError").text('.$_GET["regErr"].');';
}
```

---

### Session Variables

Submit your form as you currently do

Have some registration function like:

```
session_start();

//....

function register($username, $password,$email){

   // do some registration logic here
  if($someError){
     $_SESSION['REGISTRATION_ERROR']=$someError;
     header("Location: login.php"); // redirect the user to the login page
  }

}
```

Then on login page do something like this

```
 session_start();

 //....

if(isset($_SESSION["REGISTRATION_ERROR"])){
                echo '<script> $(function(){ $("#resistrationDiv").show();$("#resistrationError").text('.$_SESSION["REGISTRATION_ERROR"].');';
}
```

Comment: Why on earth would anyone downvote this, these are all standard ways of doing this